# Spring Boot Rest NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, https

### Problem

We are facing issues with a particular client logging in from USA to a service located in a NYC datacenter from Digitalocean. He reports a generic http connection issue. Other clients from Europe don't have problems.

I can also confirm that the client is not able to create a session with the authorization service.

### Architecture

We have a webapp, a third party SSO provider, an authorization service and a resource service. The services use HTTPS, the webapp doesn't.

The services are Spring Boot (1.4.1.RELEASE) REST controllers with `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-boot-starter-web` and `unirest-java` (1.4.9), backed by a MongoDB.

### Logs

#### Resource Service

```
2016-10-29 15:37:57.282 ERROR 5 --- [nio-8444-exec-4] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Error reading request, ignored

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1329) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:792) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
```

#### Authentication Service

```
2016-10-29 15:37:57.279 ERROR 7 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Error reading request, ignored

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1329) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:792) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
```

### Question

I have no idea why this exception pops up and only does for this particular client. Can you help me? I will provide further information.

Answer (score 3):

Based in [this topic](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/NPE-in-SecureNioChannel-TC-8-5-5-td5055259.html), it seems to be a bug in the Http11NioProtocol. As a workaround they suggest to use the Http2NioProcol.

Here is an example of how to configure the Htpp2NioProtocol in [spring boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html).

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createSslConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http2NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    try {
        File keystore = new ClassPathResource("keystore").getFile();
        File truststore = new ClassPathResource("keystore").getFile();
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setPort(8443);
        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
        protocol.setKeystorePass("changeit");
        protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststore.getAbsolutePath());
        protocol.setTruststorePass("changeit");
        protocol.setKeyAlias("apitester");
        return connector;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [" + "keystore"
                + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
    }
}
```

ps: I dont't think this will actually solve the problem, but will give you a better error message instead of NPE. I would also suggest you to get browser and OS info of the user that isn't being able to connect to your service. Maybe his computer can't resolve the certificate chain of your server certificate.